# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null [VueJs]

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I see previous questions about the same problem faced me, but I try to solve it based on the solution of the questions! but it does not work

In my `<template>`:

```
<modal name="MyModal" >
  <span class="myClass" id="visible">visible</span>
</modal>
```

In my `<script>`:

```
export default {
name: "myProject",
data: function() {
 return {}
},
methods:
 Open_EditTask: function() {

  this.$modal.show("MyModal");

  this.CurrentTask = this.MyTask;

  if ( app.EditTask.visible == true ) { document.getElementById('visible').innerHTML = 'visible'; }
  else { document.getElementById('visible').innerHTML = 'hidden'; }
 }
}
```

I used `modal` plugin to create the modal.

My problem is when the modal opened .. the text not changed based on the `app.EditTask.variable` value, but when I try to print the value of it .. it shows me the value of it either true or false.

Error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you not use computed, it's very easy.

Template:

```
<modal name="MyModal" >
  <span class="myClass" id="visible"> {{ isVisible }} </span>
</modal>
```

Javascript:

```
export default {
  name: "myProject",
  data: function() {
    return {}
  },
  methods:{
    Open_EditTask: function() {
      ..
    }
  },
  computed: {
    isVisible(){
      return app.EditTask.visible ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
    }
  }
}
```

### To change class name:

Template:

```
<modal name="MyModal" >
  <span :class="{myClass: true, hidden: !isVisible, visible: isVisible}" id="visible"></span>
</modal>
```

Javascript:

```
export default {
  name: "myProject",
  data: function() {
    return {}
  },
  methods:{
    Open_EditTask: function() {
      ..
    }
  },
  computed: {
    isVisible(){
      return app.EditTask.visible;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure you need the parentheses after the function call in the template.

Comment: Ah, yes. We do need it. Thank you.

Comment: @CongNguyen Is there any other technique to solve it because I want to use getelementbyid to change the className but I faced the same problem :(

Comment: You can change the class name with computed also.